# Identify the file type if ls -l shows ? (question mark)

Tags: files, ls

I am getting question marks and not able to identify the type of file displayed using `ls -l`. File types are always displayed as `???`.

Can you suggest a solution here?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the `ls` output that you are describing.

Comment: That happens on non-posix filesystems like FAT32 or NTFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ls -l` shows a question mark (`?`) as the first character on the line, it means that the file type is not a normal one recognized by the system. The file is not a regular file, not a directory, not a symbolic link, etc.

This can happen when you mount a non-native filesystem (for example a Solaris filesystem with doors). In this case you may or may not be able to interact with the file by opening it.

Most commonly, this happens when the filesystem has become corrupted. In this case, unmount the filesystem and run [`fsck`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck). You may have lost some data.

There's no option for `ls` to show the numerical value that encodes the file type. If you want to show the numerical file type, you can use commands such as

```
strace -e lstat ls -ld the_file
strace -e lstat stat the_file
perl -e 'printf "0%o\n", (stat($ARGV[0]))[2]' the_file
```

Knowing this numerical value is typically of little use.

Comment: The type will also show as `?` with anonymous inodes in Linux: `ls -Hl /proc/864/fd/4` => `?rw------- 1 root root 0 Oct 29 13:42 /proc/864/fd/4`. Fuse filesystems and similar can also have such files. But that's just a *single* `?` at the beginning. Having `???` in their `ls` output can happen for more banal reasons, like messed-up permissions. Telling people that "most commonly" that means that their fs is corrupted is ... not very insightful.